# using $.html(someFunction) is making my set index change events behave oddly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've stumbled on an issue on a current project that has me stumped, and I THINK it has something to do with my use of `$.html()`. Currently I'm using `$.html()` to govern when certain fields appear based on a dropdown selection. So when a change occurs to the options within the dropdown, I call the function for a specific set of fields.

For example, if 'Clerical' is selected `$.html(clerical)` runs and 
- returns the appropriate field 
- creates an object literal for a normalized, 2D database 
- sets appropriate index values to each field that is displayed.

The issue I'm having is that when I change the value in a field, even though my logs are showing me that the value is changed for the correct index, ALL objects in each index are updated to the value I just changed. A good example of this is attached to this post. I changed the value of one of the fields to xx, and while it passes the correct information, it passes the information to all areas of the object.

Any help on this would be lovely, been stuck for a while now!

[Example field update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qedp.png)

EDIT: Here are a couple of the functions in question. The first is the function that checks on which set of fields to display

---

```
formCheck: function(formID, id) {
  // run counter to get new count. Then add/remove/do nothing.                                        

  var formMap = pub.form[formName].objectMap['formMap'];
  var counts = {};

  for (var area in formMap) {
    counts[area] = formMap[area].theCount;
    formMap[area].theCount = 0;
  }

  $('.areaOfResp').each(function() {
    formMap[$(this).val()].theCount++;
  });

  for (var area in formMap) {
    var markup = pub.form[formName].templates[area](id);
    if (formMap[area].theCount > 0 && counts[area] === 0) {
      $('#' + formMap[area].id).html(markup);
    } else if (formMap[area].theCount === 0) {
      $('#' + formMap[area].id).html('');
    }
  }
},
```

---

This second function is one of field sets:

```
'Sales': function(id) {
  var form = pub.form['piq'];
  var staticAreas = form.sections.areas.updates['sales area'];
  var theStaticArea = new form.objectMap['static areas']('', '', '', 'New', 'New');
  var count = 0;

  for (var c in staticAreas.data) {
    staticAreas.data[count] = theStaticArea;
    count++;
  }
  for (var d = 0; d < 8; d++) {
    staticAreas.data[count] = theStaticArea;
    count++;
  }


  //console.log(count);
  console.log('Sales mark');

  var choiceArr = [
    ['Inside', 'Inside'],
    ['Outside', 'Outside']
  ];
  var approvalCalc = count - 3;
  var approvalAuthority = frm.field.textArea('approvalAuthority', 'Approval Authority:', 'Please elaborate if approval authority is involved', '', '', '', 'piqr', 'atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + approvalCalc + ',\'fieldType\',\'programmingLang\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + approvalCalc + ',\'categoryField\',\'Static Field\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + approvalCalc + ',\'theValue\',$(this).val());');
  var sizeCalc = count - 2;
  var portSize = frm.field.input('portSize', 'Size of Portfolio:', '', '', '', 'piqr', 'atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + sizeCalc + ',\'fieldType\',\'portSize\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + sizeCalc + ',\'categoryField\',\'Static Field\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + sizeCalc + ',\'theValue\',$(this).val());');
  var mgmtCalc = count - 1;
  var portMgmt = frm.field.input('portMgmt', 'Portfolio Management:', '', '', '', 'piqr', 'atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + mgmtCalc + ',\'fieldType\',\'portMgmt\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + mgmtCalc + ',\'categoryField\',\'Static Field\'); atlas.forms.setValue(\'piq\',\'areas\',\'sales area\',' + mgmtCalc + ',\'theValue\',$(this).val());');

  var fld =
    '<div class="case-field-sales" id="staticSales">' +
    approvalAuthority +
    portSize +
    portMgmt +
    '</div>';
  return fld;
},
```

Comment: Can you include text of `html` and `javascript` at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated with a couple samples from the project. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: I have not, the SharePoint site on which I'm putting this together is not currently set up to work with VS projects. Sad too because that would probably help a lot. Do you think I should log the results in a specific place?